# angularjs : html header refresh after loggedin

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to have a different header in my index.html (loggedout) and my home page (loggedin). I've tried many solution but my header never refresh. I always need to reload the page to make it work.

index.html

```
<div id="header" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl as head">
  <div ng-show="head.loggedIn" class="header">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a ng-href="#/about">About</a></li>
      <li><a ng-click="head.logout()">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div ng-show="head.loggedOut" class="header">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a ng-click="head.login()">Home</a></li>
      <li><a ng-href="#/register">Sign in</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div ng-view=""></div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
   <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

app.js
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

```
app.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope) {
   var head = this;
   head.logout = logout;
   head.loggedIn = 'false';
   head.loggedOut = !head.loggedIn;

   function logout(){
     head.loggedIn ="false";
     head.loggedOut = 'true';
    }

    function logint(){
      head.loggedIn ="false";
      head.loggedOut = 'true';
    }
});
```

Here is my simply code on Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/byNHePeJskAdQbPvFWLp?p=preview

Any solution to manage different header/footer with a loggedIn var ?

Comment: Stop using strings instead of booleans. And don't use more than one boolean. The other oen is redundant, since it always has the inverse value.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I take your comment in mind but it still doesn't work event in your PLUNKR. I'd like to change menu when you click on "home" or after "logout"

Comment: I never posted any plunkr. You're answering to the wrong guy. But here's one that works: http://plnkr.co/edit/QO6RzzQJ72UariAvdFyT?p=preview. Key facts: it uses a single boolean, not strings. It registers the login function on the controller. It fixes its spelling. It fixes its body.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake and thank you for the correction ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use without `""`

try to use as `boolean` instead of `string`

like this

```
head.loggedIn =false;
```

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/xBwkPwVkzsslNzoaYeE1?p=preview)